# Populate Dropdown Select with Props React

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-bootstrap

So I am trying to populate the dropdown with some info from another table using props. Currently have this. I had to do the loop backwards because earlier it was breaking,

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import {
  Button,
  ControlLabel,
  FormGroup,
  Form,
  FormControl
} from 'react-bootstrap';

class UserForm extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  createPosItems() {
    const posItems = [];
    console.log('heyyyy', this.props);
    for (let i = this.props.position.length; i > this.props.position.length; i--) {
      posItems.push(<option key={i} value={this.props.position.i}>{this.props.position.position_name}</option>);
    }
    return posItems;
  }

  createTeamItems() {
    const teamItems = [];
    console.log('whyyyyy', this.props);
    for (let i = this.props.team.length; i > this.props.team.length; i--) {
      teamItems.push(<option key={i} value={this.props.team.i}>{this.props.team.team_name}</option>);
    }
    return teamItems;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-lg-12">
          <Form>
            <FormGroup controlId="employeeFirstName">
              <ControlLabel>First Name</ControlLabel>
              <FormControl
                type="text"
                name="firstName"
                required=""
                value={this.props.user.firstName}
                onChange={this.props.onChange}
              />
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup controlId="empEmail">
              <ControlLabel>Email</ControlLabel>
              <FormControl
                type="email"
                name="email"
                required=""
                value={this.props.user.email}
                onChange={this.props.onChange}
              />
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup controlId="position">
              <ControlLabel>Job Position</ControlLabel>
              <FormControl
                componentClass="select"
              >
                <option value="">Select a Position</option>
                {this.createPosItems()}
              </FormControl>
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup controlId="Team">
              <ControlLabel>Team</ControlLabel>
              <FormControl
                componentClass="select"
              >
                <option value="">Select a Team</option>
                {this.createTeamItems()}
              </FormControl>
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup>
              <Button
                pullRight
                type="submit"
                className="btn btn-success"
                disabled={this.props.saving}
                onClick={this.props.onSave}
              >Save</Button>

              <Button
                pullRight
                type="submit"
                className="btn btn-danger pull-right"
                // onClick={this.props.onDelete}
              >Delete</Button>
            </FormGroup>
          </Form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

UserForm.propTypes = {
  user: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  team: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  position: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  onSave: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onChange: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  saving: React.PropTypes.bool
};

export default UserForm;
```

The forms is a child of another page. Every other field works, expect for the drop downs, the element shows up, but doesn't populate the drop down. Have tried using multiple people's examples, and still cannot get it to run. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see, your for loop is causing the problem. Let say that the `this.props.team.length` would be equal to `10`. Then your loop would look like this:

`for (let i = 10; i > 10; i--) { ... }`

This code inside this for-loop would never be executed, because the condition is wrong. Basically it says, start with `i = 10` and while `i` is bigger than `10` execute the code and then substract `1` from `i`.

But the problem is that `10` is not bigger than `10`, and so the loop never gets executed. If I express this using the `i` variable, `i` can never be bigger than `i`.

This is the updated loop that should work:

`for (let i = this.props.team.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { ... }`

Using this loop you render the options from the end (last index of the `this.props.team` array) to the index of 0.

If you wanted to start from the beginning, you would write this for-loop:

`for (let i = 0; i < this.props.team.length; i++) { ... }`

I'd also recommend you to use `Array.prototype.map` and to write only one function for populating the options, there is no need to repeat yourself. And using this approach, the array into which you store `<option>`s is not necessary. You could write such function like this:

```
populateOptions(options) {
  return options.map((option, index) => (
    <option key={index} value={option}>{option}</option>
  ));
}
```

Then you'd call this function in this fashion:

`this.populateOptions(this.props.team)`

or

`this.populateOptions(this.props.position)`

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is the documentation for the `Array.prototype.map` function.

Answer (score 1):

You just create a variable from props like this:

```
const {organizations} = this.props;
```

And the use it to fill the dropdown in a `render()` method like this:

```
<DropdownButton title="Organization" className="m-b m-t" id="dropdown-organization">
                    {organizations.map((organization, i) =>
    <MenuItem key={i}>{organization.name}</MenuItem>)}
</DropdownButton>
```

The `onClick` handlers can be passed down via props the same way.